# Binary OR operator in java comparing chars

Tags: java, logic

I'm stuck on something simple, basically I want to validate the following

```
public class CharTest
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        char myChar = '(';
        if (myChar != '(' | ')' )
        {
            System.out.println("Fault");
        }
        System.out.println("No Fault");
    }
}
```

But I keep getting

CharTest.java:6: error: bad operand types for binary operator '|'
                if (myChar != '(' | ')' )
                                  ^
  first type:  boolean
  second type: char
1 error

I've tried using |  as well as ||  how can I achieve the OR functionality that I'm looking for?

Comment: There was a question like this 15 minutes ago, please use the search function.

Comment: if (myChar != '(' || myChar != ')')

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar this will produce the wrong behavior.

Comment: @HugoDozois Yes. But i gave example how to use pipe (or condition)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java has a [defined syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9) for use in an `if` statement. Having an expression with more than one RHS operand violates the syntax so the compiler complains. Rather than a bitwise operator, a logical operator would be preferrable here due to the [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) it provides.

A logical OR with a negative expression on both sides will *always* be true. Use `&&` instead:

```
if (myChar != '(' && myChar != ')' )
```

Answer (score 4):

### Reason

Binary operator can be used on `boolean|boolean` or `number|number`. In your case 
since [`!=` have higher priority then `|`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

```
myChar != '(' | ')'
```

is equal to

```
( myChar!='(' ) | ')'
```

which gives you

```
    boolean     | character
```

But even if you would write it like this `myChar !=( '(' | ')' )` binary OR would calculate 
`'(' | ')'` into `)` because

```
'(' ->     101000
')' ->     101001
 OR        ------
'('|')'->  101001 -> `)`
```

so `(` condition would be lost.

### Solution

You probably want to use this form based on [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): !(a OR b)== !a AND !b

```
myChar != '(' & myChar != ')'
```

or even Short-Circuit `and` to improve performance

```
myChar != '(' && myChar != ')'
```

This way if `myChar != '('` will return false entire condition will be estimated to false since 
`false` `and` `anything` gives always false.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following

```
if (myChar != '(' && myChar != ')' )
```

You have to separate the comparison and use the logical `&&` and operator.

[See an example on logical operators](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/45.html)

According to [De Morgan's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you have to use the `and` operator to achieve what you want to do. Else it would be accepting everything. The and will enforce that you don't want either of the character.

Answer (score 1):

You can't say "isn't equal to this char or this char".  Java makes you compare against each character individually.

```
if (myChar != '(' && myChar != ')')
```

Note you want `&&` here, because (1) "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)", and (2) we care about the boolean values, not the bits (making `&` look odd here).

Answer (score 0):

You should do it this way

```
(myChar != '(' && myChar!= ')')
```

`|` is not a logical operator its a `Bitwise inclusive OR`.

**The bitwise | operator performs a bitwise inclusive OR operation.**

Answer (score 0):

I think the operator "|" returns true or false, this cannot be validated against the character value.

The following should work :

```
if (!((myChar==')')||(myChar=='(')) ){
    System.out.println("Fault");
}
```

Comment: This will not produce the good behavior

Comment: @Hugo Dozois : what you want to say ??

Comment: This will match any expression with a `)` or a `(`. Which is not wanted. You have to put a logical and `&&` between the statements

Comment: Yes this is logically correct!